# Cakephp validation issue

Tags: validation, cakephp, boolean

Hey guys got an issue with Cakephp validation..

I want to know why is partytwo validation going straight to false?

Here is my Relationship model:

```
<?php
    class Relationship extends AppModel{
        var $name='Relationship';
        public $useTable = 'relationships_users';
        public $primaryKey = 'id';

        var $validate = array(
            'date' => array(
                'rule' => array('datevalidation', 'systemDate'),
                'message' => 'Current Date and System Date is mismatched'
            ),
            'partytwo'=>array(
                'partytwoExists'=>array(
                    'rule'=> 'userExists',
                    'message'=>'That username doesnt exist.'
                )
            )
        );

        function datevalidation( $field=array(), $compare_field=null ) {
            if ($field['date'] > $compare_field)
                return TRUE;
            else
                return FALSE;
        }

        function userExists($check) {
            $userExists= $this->find('count', array('conditions'=>$check));
            if($userExists == 1) {
                return TRUE;
            }else{
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
 ...
```

Comment: Well, what's in your `$check` param anyway?

Comment: `$check` holds the field you want to validate. `$this->data` holds the current data you're trying to validate/save. With that in mind, update your code. Your goal in userExists method to check if the user id from your data exists in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CakePHP book [Adding Your Own Validation Methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods) section, a custom rule that wrote like this

```
'rule' => array('datevalidation', 'systemDate')
```

means Cake will runs your `datevalidation` method like this:

```
$valid = $Relationships->datevalidation(array(
    'date' => 'some user input value'
), 'systemDate');
```

With the same fashion,

```
'rule' => array('userExists')
```

causes Cake to run

```
$valid = $Relationships->userExists(array(
    'partytwo' => 'some user input value'
));
```

*(Simulated calls. Actual calling is using `dispatchMethod` at [line 3155](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/model#l-3155) of Model.php)*

So you are most probably need to rewrite your `datevalidation` method. Furthermore, your code

```
$userExists= $this->find('count', array('conditions'=>$check));
```

`$userExists` can return you a number larger or equal to 0. Your logic is wrong if it returns 2 or more. Consider `Model::hasAny` instead. It could be the reason why it is always validated as `false` for your case.